# ype 'Observable<QuestionBase<string>[]>' is missing the following properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a API that returns some data in form of a JSON doc an can have 2 levels, one is the parent and then some parents can have children. Currently i am reading the json doc and use the forEach loop to create new Objects in an Array. As for the child's i check if there is any children in the array and if so pass it to another function to go and parse the Children and then Set the parent with the newly created Document. All seems to work except one thing, when i try to sort my new Array of Object i get an error

The code i use

```
buildChild(data : any){
let children : QuestionBase<string>[] = []

if( data.children &&  data.children.length > 0){
  data.children.forEach(child => {
    switch(child.type) { 
      case 'TextboxQuestion': { 
        children.push(new TextboxQuestion({
          key: child.key,
          label: child.label,
          value: child.value,
          placeholder: child.placeholder,
          order: child.order,
          required: child.required,
          function: child.function,
          class: child.class,
          style: child.style,
          childhidekey: child.childhidekey,
          childhidevalue: child.childhidevalue
        }))
        break; 
      }
      case 'RadioButtonQuestion': { 
        children.push(new RadioButtonQuestion({
          key: child.key,
          label: child.label,
          value: child.value,
          placeholder: child.placeholder,
          order: child.order,
          required: child.required,
          function: child.function,
          class: child.class,
          style: child.style,
          options: child.options,
          childhidekey: child.childhidekey,
          childhidevalue: child.childhidevalue
        }))
        break; 
      }
      case 'CheckboxQuestion': { 
        this.questions.push(new CheckboxQuestion({
          key: child.key,
          label: child.label,
          value: child.value,
          placeholder: child.placeholder,
          order: child.order,
          required: child.required,
          function: child.function,
          class: child.class,
          style: child.style,
          options: child.options,
          childhidekey: child.childhidekey,
          childhidevalue: child.childhidevalue
        }))
         break; 
      } 
    }}
  )

 // return children
  return of(children.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order));
      } }
```

The Error is

> Type 'Observable<QuestionBase[]>' is missing the following
> properties from type 'QuestionBase[]': length, pop, push,
> concat, and 25 more.

Also maybe there is a better way to do this then my approach, so any pointers are helpful and appreciated

[Stackblitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i57uud?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through your stackblitz sample. The problem is in `buildChild()` method and `question-base.ts`

1. your `question-base.ts` declares this as type of `children` property:

```
  style: string;
  children?: QuestionBase<T>[]
  childhidekey?: string;
```

2. but your `buildChild` method returns an observable:

```
     // return children
      return of(children.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order));
```

To fix this simply remove the `of` from `buildChild`, and voila it works  :

```
return children.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert `JS` object to JSON back and forth to remove all object function.

```
children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(children))
```

and this is the result: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e4h4a8)